# Auto-Unboxing of object

Tags: c#, casting, boxing, autoboxing

I've done a bit of research on this and it seems pretty impossible but none of the answers have been specific enough to my issue. I currently have a `Stack<object>` that I push objects of multiple different types to. Before I push them I box them to `object` so it accepts them. Is there any possible way of automatically unboxing the object to the original unboxed type?

Comment: What do you mean by "Automatically"? Without any code? I think it is impossible.

Comment: I mean, something like this... `(thingy.GetType())thingy`

Comment: well, `(thingy.GetType())thingy` type of `thingy` is object, so you are converting `Object` to `Object`

Comment: I know, I want to know how to cast or unbox to its original type without knowing the explicit type name (or having it hard coded). Both Java and Python have this /:

Comment: There has to be some commonality here, otherwise, how would you know what objects were in the stack and thus which members existed?

Comment: @jduncanator, I agree with Hardrada, there is something missing here. Unboxing isn't the problem, it's doable, but how do you intend to manipulate the unboxed value if you don't know its type? That would either result in boxing again, or many `if` branches for each handled type. You don't need to unbox explicitly to read object properties: reflection and `dynamic` are here.

Comment: No, I sort of know the expected type, the documentation specifies that each type that is in the stack will have a property of name. But the thing is the types returned by the stack could be of a theoretically unlimited type. Ok I thought of dynamic types, but couldn't find any examples... Mind posting something?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the extension method `OfType<OneOfTheTypes>()` to get only those objects of that specific types casted to the correct type.

You can not automatically convert an object to a variable with the compile time type of a compatible type of the runtime type the object has.
The type of a variable is a compile time type and if the content is not known by the compiler to be of that type at compile time. The compiler does not know what runtime type each object in your stack actually has. You have to make a promise to the compiler (with a cast) that the runtime type will actually match the compile time type.

But to be frank. This kind of "check what type I have" is a typical smell of a bad design. Try to design your code with a common base class if you have similar types of objects or use different kinds of storage for different kind of objects.

Comment: Its a Flash ByteCode parser that pushes and pops different types to and from a stack of type object. I need to be able to obtain them in their original type after being popped so I can read their properties.

Answer (score 0):

There is no **Automagic** way to do it.

try this though

`var objT = (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(T));`

```
var tuple = new  Tuple<object, Type>(someObject, typeof(someObject));

stack.Push(tuple);
```

Comment: @jduncanator you might want to push a `Tuple` into `Stack` instaed. `Stack<Tuple<object, Type>>`, than you can just use the type from the `Tuple` you get back

Comment: I was thinking of this, but I thought I'd ask before I made an assumption. Would a generic method help?

Comment: @jduncanator generic method for what?

Comment: Casting? Doesn't the compiler infer the generic type from the type of the parameters?

Comment: But how can I cast the returned object to T without knowing what T is? Or is that statement meant to be in a Generic method already?

Comment: well the returned object will be a `Tuple` and it contains the object and it's type, so all you need to do is cast the object to the type from Tuple

Comment: Ahh Alright. Sorry, missed the part where this applied to the stack of Tuple :P

Comment: @jduncanator please accept the answer if this worked for you.

Comment: I don't see what purpose the `Tuple` serves here. You just stored a type that you already have using `GetType()`.

Comment: Yes, Upon further investigation, .GetType on a boxed object gets the original unboxed type. Also adding a breakpoint and browsing the values of the stack, Visual Studio automatically casts it back to its original type and displays its value(s) in the little popup window. Also you can't cast with a type object. The compiler doesn't accept it.